# When flipping a fair coin $100$ times, probability of at least $50$ heads given there are at least $40$ heads

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

## The Question:

You flip a fair coin $100$ times. What is the probability of getting at least
$50$ heads given that you have at least $40$ heads.

Hi .. Im new to this world called probability. 
I'm trying to solve this question as binomial distribution .
yet Im not sure if my thoughts are right, hope you guys check my answer

## The answer:

sample of $n =  100$ of independent trials each of which can have only two possible outcomes, which are either “head” or “tail” >> its binomial distribution

$n = 100,p = 0.5,q = 0.5$

$X \sim B(100, 0.5)$

$P(A) =  P(x\ge50)  =  1  - P(x\le49) =  1 – .460  =  .540$

$P(B) = P(x\ge40)  = 1- P(x\le39) = 1 – 0.018 = 0.982$

$P(A \cap B) = P( 50\ge x\ge40) =  P(x\le50)  -  P(x\le39)  = 0.540 – 0.018 = 0.522$

$P(A|B) =  P(A \cap B) / P(B) =  0.522 / 0.982 = 0.531$

Answer (score 2):

The event $A\cap B$ is the event that the number of heads is at least $50$, **and** at least $40$.  This is the same as saying that the number is at least $50$.  That is, $A\cap B=A$ and so
$$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{0.540}{0.982}=0.550$$
(assuming your calculations for $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are correct - I didn't check them).

Comment: thanx _david !_

Comment: there is a minor rounding issue: $\frac{0.5397946}{0.9823999}\approx 0.5494653$ would be closer

Comment: Thanks for that @Henry.  Of course the probability will actually be a rational number.  Do you think you could calculate that and post it, so that we have no error at all?